# Titanium - Facebook permissions error when asking read and write permissions

Tags: facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've read in the documentation that since Facebook sdk change read and write permissions should now be asked differently.

If not, the Facebook SDK throws the following error:

```
Publish or manage permissions are not permitted to be requested with read permissions.
```

In my app what I'm doing is in login setting the `permissions` property. And I want the user to know up front what permissions he is agreeing to when he registers.

So my question is what is the correct way to handle this? I searched the error and saw answers that are relevant to native code. What is the "correct" way to work with Titanium to ask Facebook permissions? up front just ask read permissions and then bother the user again later to give write permissions?

Comment: _“And I want the user to know up front what permissions he is agreeing to when he registers”_ – well then _tell them_, if you think it is that important. // Facebook’s best practices for login explicitly state that you should only ask for permissions the first time you use them. And users should be used to that by now as well. So if you ask them for publishing permission the first time they try and publish something via your app, that should totally suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down to *Manage Read and Write Permissions* at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook to see how you can request additional permissions.